# Vector layer is showing gap which is not marked in red, how to correct the problem

Tags: qgis, topology

[image]I am working in a QGIS layer with more than 450 polygons. When I am checking with the topology checker for any error, it shows two gaps, but they are **not visible in red**, and one polygon is being highlighted at random. After that, the project **suddenly hangs** and I cannot do anything further in the layer. I tried restarting QGIS, uninstalling, and reinstalling, but nothing worked.
I am using **QGIS 3.34**

Comment: Can you add screenshots of the data?

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS.SE. I included an answer about what i think that the problem is. But the error you are facing is not something we can reproduce without your data. So your question, as it is written, is not something we can answer in a canonical way. Please, edit the post to include more information. Screenshots are welcome, but i think a sample of error data must be shared to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You might run a v.clean with a suitable snap tolerance (you might try several, the layers produced are temporary) and then check the result for topology errors.  If you have a spatial index you might remove it and test things again.

Answer (score 1):

The error can be in the user profile or in the validity of geometries.

To check if it is in the user profile, go to Settings, User Profiles, and create a new profile. Give it a name, accept and then close the previous QGIS window (the one opened with the older profile).

After that, check if the problem is in the validity of geometries by running the Check Validity tool from the toolbox.
It will output three layers, one with valid geometries, another one with invalid geometries, and a third one with errors. The error output has points for each invalidation and the reason in the attributes table.

Sometimes you can fix the validity automatically with the Fix Geonetries tool. Run it and check the validity again.

Comment: Tried all these, but they have not solved the problem.